# Search for files in a Git repository doesn't work

Tags: eclipse, git

I want to use Git with eclipse (Neon 2). For that I went to the "Git Perspective", clone a repository, create a new branch from "master" and found some files under "Working Tree". So far it works as expected.
But now I lookup for a specific file so I open the resource dialog (Ctrl+Shift+r) and type part of the filename. But nothing is found.
So I tried it with the file search (Ctrl+h) and lookup for some keywords and it's the some problem: No file is found.
Is this an eclipse bug or is it my mistake?